# Different output rather than expected one

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Hello I am a high school student. Recently I started to do some programming in c++. But I'm stuck with the example below. I would appreciate it if you people could help me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int j;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        i=j;

    }
    cout<<j;


}
```

Why is the output: `2686864`?

Instead I think it should be `0123456789`, as the loop starts from 0. Thank you for any suggestions. .

Comment: it should be j=i and cout should be inside loop

Comment: `int j;` makes no sense because it initializes `j` with random garbage.

Answer (score 3):

what you want to do is pobably this:

```
int main()
{

    int j;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        j=i;
        cout<<j;
    }


}
```

of course, you don't need the variable j here at all; you can simply output i

Comment: @user5922850 this is absolutely what you want to do to see the output you desire. I explained it in words, but perhaps this is more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't assigned a value to `j` in your declaration. In your loop the assignment is always to `i`, because of the order of the equals sign, and in fact you're always assigning to `i` the uninitialized value of `j` from outside your loop. So `j` remains at the seemingly crazy value it was initially set to be.

You want to assign the value of `i` to `j` inside the loop, i.e. reverse the equality, if you want to see it change. Also if you want to see more than one output, you need to move your print statement inside the for loop.

What you're seeing as output is not the output of multiple print statements - it's the single number automatically assigned to the initial value of `j`, because you didn't give it a value when you declared it. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

First, variable "j" is not initialized. Then you are setting your loop variable to the value of j.

It looks like you're trying to build a string "0123456789", in which case, you need make j a string, and concatenate the character for each number to the end of the string in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are looping while i < 10 and i starts at 0. If you want to set j = i then you need to switch the order of the variables because if not it could mess up the loop, but not necessarily in this situation.

Also you should initialize j to some value because if not you will get garbage values.

Also it won't output it the way you are wanting it. You should move the cout statement inside the for loop to get the out put you desire.